# Can I use new MD3 progress bars right now?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-you

I am developing an EPUB reader for Android with Material You design in mind.

I have been following the guidelines from [the official website](https://m3.material.io) and have created a Figma design file based on the components supplied with the documentation, one of them being this `LinearProgressIndicator` (right under the book cover).

[image: The components in question (Figma design file)]

[This page](https://m3.material.io/components/progress-indicators/overview) also suggests that progress indicators should indeed look like this.

However, upon rendering my views still show the old one:

[image: The old progress indicator]

My `dependencies` in `build.gradle.kts` look like this:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics-android:1.5.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
}
```

I have tried updating `implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")` to the newest beta (`androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta02` at the moment), but still no luck.

Please note that this is my first experience with Jetpack Compose or even Android development as a whole, so I might be missing something otherwise obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your Compose BOM is out-of-date. Try this one:

```
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
```

Comment: Thank you! That, unfortunately, did not help.